# Post a dynamic input form and fetch the array

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue with my dynamic input form. Its for our new Adminportal (We can manage our meals and drinks there)
So the dynamic form looks like that:

```
   ...Add Row</button>
<br />
<div class="rowFields<?= $id; ?>">
<div>
<input type="text" name="newMealName[]" placeholder="Name" style="width:30%"/>
<input type="text" name="newMealDescription[]" placeholder="Description" style="width:50%" />
<input type="number" step="0.01" name="newMealPrice[]" placeholder="0.01" style="width:15%" />
<a href="#" id="remove_row">Remove</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I am adding more rows or remove them via JQuery - that works fine.
I am passing the form with my Ajax script, I am using for other inserts to our database as well - this works!

My PHP insert script for this one looks like that:

```
<?php
...

$nameArray = $_POST['newMealName'];
$descriptionArray = $_POST['newMealDescription'];
$priceArray = $_POST['newMealPrice'];

$sqlAddNewMeals = $db->prepare("insert into tableX(name, description, price) values(?, ?, ?)");

for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($nameArray); $i++)
{
    $sqlAddNewMeals->bind_param('ssd', $_POST['newMealName'][$i], $_POST['newMealDescription'][$i], $_POST['newMealPrice'][$i]);
    $sqlAddNewMeals->execute();
}

$sqlAddNewMeals->close();
?>
```

I have tried to use

```
$sqlAddNewMeals->bind_param('ssdi', $nameArray[$i],...
```

but this doesn't work either.
I have one last idea, but want to discuss with you before doing that:
Do I have to bind params like $name, $description and use a for loop like that:

```
forloop {
$name=$nameArray[1];
...
$sql->execute(); }
```

Thanks in advance,
pl44

edit 1:
AJAX to pass the form

```
$(function () {

    $("button#addNewMeals").click(function () {
        var menu_id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "XXX/add-new-menu.php",
            data: $('form.manageMenu-'+menu_id).serialize(),
            success: function () {
                alert("Added.");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: *..values(meal_id, ?, ?, ?)* Why meal_id as value? And, *"..I am passing the form with my Ajax script.."* Please paste that code too.

Comment: you are right, I can delete it - it will auto_increment anyway

Comment: *..bind_param('ssdi'* But, passing 3 values. Check Properly @pl44

Comment: Any error coming? If yes, please paste that error line too. Check in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to fix it by myself. I used this logic:

1. Prepare Stmt
2. Save passed arrays to values and fetch them to another array
3. Bind_param with variables like $name, $desc etc.
4. for loop to declare $name = nameArray[0], $desc = $descArray[0]...
5. execute the statement WITHIN the for loop
6. close statement after for loop

ANd it´s working now. Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
$nameArray = $_POST['newMealName'];
$descriptionArray = $_POST['newMealDescription'];
$priceArray = $_POST['newMealPrice'];
$sqlAddNewMeals = $db->prepare("insert into tableX(name, description, price) values(?, ?, ?)");
$param = array();
for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($nameArray); $i++)
{
$param[$i]['newMealName'] =  $_POST['newMealName'][$i];
$param[$i]['newMealDescription'] =  $_POST['newMealDescription'][$i];
$param[$i]['newMealPrice'] =  $_POST['newMealPrice'][$i]; 
}

print_r($param);

?>
```

Comment: Can You Explain What It Will Do?

Comment: looks like we are fetching the array. do I have to bind $param[$i]['newMealName'] etc after that?